# Passing variable through function Javascript / PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, get, onclick

i want to pass a variable through to a php on an onClick event, it doesn't seem to be passing it through to the page properly though.

Here's my html

```
<a href="data.php" onClick="video(We Have a Pope)" hidefocus="">
```

and the relevant javascript function

```
function video(result) {
  $('#information').load('data.php?result=' + result);
  document
}
```

My php page looks like this

```
<?php

$result = $_GET['result'];
echo $result;
?>
```

Nothing is being outputted though :S

Comment: `onClick="video('We Have a Pope')"`

Answer (score 3):

`onClick="video(We Have a Pope)"` should be `onClick="video('We Have a Pope')"`

Comment: You can easily tell by this site's syntax highlighting, where the error is. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need quotation marks when you pass string as parameter, like this:

```
<a href="data.php" onClick="video('We Have a Pope')" hidefocus="">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="data.php" onClick="javascript:video('We Have a Pope');" hidefocus="">
```

Comment: You don't need a javascript:-pseudo URI for the onclick attribute.

Comment: In that context, it isn't a URI, the `javascript:` part is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick="video('We Have a Pope');"
```

or

```
onClick="video(\"We Have a Pope\");"
```

Comment: `\\` is not an HTML escape character. Why are you adding a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) when there is no loop?